# What "long chain of carbon chemistry" in the interstellar medium produces cyclopropenylidene? (C3H2)

Tags: interstellar-medium, astrochemistry

Wikipedia's [Cyclopropenylidene; Titan (Moon of Saturn); Formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclopropenylidene#Titan_(Moon_of_Saturn))says:

> The major formation reaction of c-C3H2 is the dissociative recombination of c-C3H3+.
>
> C3H3+ + e− → C3H2 + H
>
> c-C3H3+ is a product of a long chain of carbon chemistry that occurs in the ISM.

From that I conclude that Cyclopropenylidene in the ISM (interstellar medium) *is also* a product of a long chain of carbon chemistry.

**Question *What* "long chain of carbon chemistry" in the interstellar medium produces cyclopropenylidene? (C3H2)

---

**note:** While [Detection of Cyclopropenylidene on Titan with ALMA](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-3881/abb679/meta) is interesting news, my question is about the ISM, not (necessarily at least) Titan's upper atmosphere.

Comment: Well indeed the Wikipedia article just shift the "problem" of formation from the carbene to the conjugated cation. Perhaps you can try posting on Chemistry SE.

Comment: @Alchimista those knowledgable about, and how to research about conditions in the interstellar medium are more likely to see this question here than there. I did post a link to this question in chat there earlier.

Comment: You might find refs in this paper https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2982172/#!po=2.23881 The paper itself is more on the influx of molecules to Earth but in the intro mentions C chemistry in ISM.

Comment: http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1990A%26A...239..319M